# API Call Before Next Iteration Starts in Loop

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

I would like to send a POST request to a certain app through their API. What I am trying to do is to process the input data (called data) and send a POST request on one record by one record in the loop. Then, I delete the corresponding object in data for optimization purpose. I know that because of the asynchronous feature of JavaScript, the loop finishes before the function gets called. However, even though I wrap the api function in IIFE or wrap it in an async function with await(the code is below), the compiler still gives me function calls with the same parameter which is the last object. So, when I see created records on the app, David's information was generated three times. The screenshot below is each record object after being processed. If you could tell me ways of triggering the api call before the next iteration in the loop, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
const obj = [];
var record = {};
var data = [
    {
        "userId": "123",
        "name": "John",
        "phoneNumber": "123-456-6789"
    },
    {
        "userId": "345",
        "name": "Summer",
        "phoneNumber": "535-631-9742"
    },
    {
        "userId" : "789",
        "name": "David",
        "phoneNumber": "633-753-1352"
    }
]

var dataLen = data.length;
var people = data;

createKeyValue = ((key, value) => {
    var temp = {};
    temp["value"] = value;
    obj[key] = temp;
});

apiCall = ((record) => {
    clientInformation.record.addRecord.then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

async function asyncFunction(record) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => apiCall(record), 1000)
    });
    let result = await promise;
    console.log(result);
}

while (dataLen > 0) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data[0])) {
        switch(key) {
            case 'userId':
                createKeyValue(key, value);
                break;
            case 'name':
                createKeyValue(key, value);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
    
    record["record"] = obj;
    asyncFunction(record);
    data.shift();
    dataLen -= 1;

    
}
```

Here is the screenshot of how each processed data looks like.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your `apiCall` doesn't `return` anything, the `asyncFunction` never `resolve()`s the promise that it uses, and the `while` loop doesn't use `await` as it should.

Comment: Each time you replace the `obj` value, that's why you have 3 times Davids details

Comment: ```@Bergi``` So, should the ```apiCall``` return the resp as its return value? Also, could you please explain where ```await``` should be placed in the ```while``` loop?

Comment: ```Marios``` Yes, I noticed what you mentioned, but if you could tell me, how can I get it fixed from here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't understand how the `for loop` inside the `while` works. The `data` should be incremented each time to get the next array inside `data`.

The `data[0] => { userId: 123 ... }, data[1] => { userId: 345 ... } and so on` .

At each `for loop` iteration checks the 3 elements of each sub array, so each time `temp` stores the key values for `userId and name`. So when the loop finishes, the `temp` contains as `key => userId, name` and the corresponding values.

```js
    var data = [
        {
            "userId": "123",
            "name": "John",
            "phoneNumber": "123-456-6789"
        },
        {
            "userId": "345",
            "name": "Summer",
            "phoneNumber": "535-631-9742"
        },
        {
            "userId" : "789",
            "name": "David",
            "phoneNumber": "633-753-1352"
        }
    ]

    var dataLen = data.length;
        
    let i = 0 ;
        while ( i < dataLen) {
            
            let temp = [];
            
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data[i])) {
                
             if(key == 'userId' || key == 'name'){
                   temp[key] = value;   
                  }
                                
        }
            
                //Just to print the values and understand
            for(let k in temp){
                      console.log(k+" -> "+temp[k]);
                }
             
              //here you will pass the temp values to functions
              console.log(" At each iteration execute the required functions ");
            
              //asyncFunction(temp);
              i += 1;

            
       }
```